# A difficulty in understanding Shur`s lemma (part a).

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

The lemma and its proof is given in the following picture:

I do not know why the kernel of $f$ is either 0 or M and why the image of $f$ is either 0 or N, and why if the kernel is 0 and the image is N this leads to $f$ to be an isomorphism? could anyone clarify this for me please?

thanks!!

[image]

Comment: (i) $M$ is a simple module, (ii) $N$ is a simple module, (iii) the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: I can understand maybe needing to ask the first two questions, but if you really don't understand why they imply the third, I think you need to slow down your rate of posting questions and think about things a little more on your own.

Comment: I also think you should do far less `*picture*, i don't understand this picture/statements in picture, clarify??` as this shows no effort on your part.

Comment: Please use mathjax when you typeset your questions. And also, try to include your attempts and thoughts on the question. You've been asking several questions with the same "style" showing no much effort, posting pictures, so I suggest you to change that style.

Comment: Ok , I will improve my style, thank to you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel and image must be $R$-submodules of $M$ and $N$ respectively. If $M$ is assumed to be simple, then by definition the only $R$-submodules of $M$ are $\{0\}$ and $M$. Similarly for $N$.

For your second question, note the following two facts:

- $\ker f = M$ if and only if $\operatorname{im} f = \{0\}$.
- If $\ker f = \{0\}$ and $\operatorname{im} f = N$, then $f$ is a bijection.