# How can I prove that the following function is bounded?

Tags: functions

How can I prove that the following function is bounded?

$$f(x) = \frac{1-x^2}{4 + x^2},$$

And I wonder if the following 2 hints may help?

**Hints:**

1. $(x + 1)^2 \geq 0.$
2. $(x - 1)^2 \geq 0.$

thanks!

Comment: This is a straightforward adaptation of [this problem here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2471368/how-can-i-prove-that-this-function-is-bounded-using-the-given-2-hints), to the point that I'm voting to close as duplicate. Please take the time to read and *think about* the answers you get instead of immediately reasking.

Comment: Since the function has so vertical asymptotes and is symmetrical, wouldn’t showing $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}=-1$ suffice?

Comment: @user296602  you are wrong ..... it is not a duplicate .... the function is different.

Comment: @Intuition You sure you want to use your hints? None of the answers uses the hints given.

Comment: @velutluna ..... my statement is clear ..... I am asking if these 2 hints are used here or no.

Comment: @Intuition [Relevant related comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2469562/a-difficulty-in-understanding-shurs-lemma-part-a#comment5102575_2469562), especially given the rapid fire follow-up questions you've asked in this thread. Not to mention the fact that Zhuoran's answer in the linked thread would absolutely have covered this function as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rewrite $f(x)$ in canonical form:
$$f(x)=\frac{5-(4+x^2)}{4+x^2}=-1+\frac{5}{4+x^2}$$
so we get tightest possible bounds:
$$-1<f(x)\le-1+\frac54=\frac14.$$

Comment: That's actual very sharp. No derivative needed....+1

Comment: Very nice... +1

Answer (score 2):

Using the triangle inequality,

$$|f(x)| = \left|\frac{1-x^{2}}{4+x^{2}}\right| = \left|\frac{x^{2}-1}{4+x^{2}}\right| \leq \left|\frac{x^{2}}{4+x^{2}}\right| + \left|\frac{1}{4+x^{2}}\right|< 1+1/4=5/4$$

Therefore $f(x)$ always falls between $-5/4$ and $5/4$, hence it is bounded.

Comment: Check your lower bound again....

Answer (score 2):

The denominator is always positive (never zero) and for the numerator, we can write $-x^2<-x^2+1\le1$. Now you can conclude....

Comment: When equality with 1 happens?

Comment: For $x=0$ (Compare $y=-x^2+1$ with $y=1$ using a graphing tool)

Comment: so the upper bound of the function is 1, what about the lower bound?

Comment: @Intuition The (least) upper bound is not $1$. Should be $1/4$.

Comment: why ? @velutluna

Comment: Are you interested in an upper and lower bound, or are you interested in the actual Range of your function? These are two different things.

Comment: I am proving that the function is bounded (meaning that I must find the upper & lower bound for it)@imranfat

Comment: In that case, my answer suffices.

Comment: @Intuition Any upper and lower bounds are ok?

Comment: @velutluna could you write your clarification please? what if I want the least upper bound and the greatest lower bound?

Comment: @Intuition Bernard's answer does not only give you upper and lower bound, it gives you the Range of the function. In my view the best answer. Obviously arriving at such an answer takes somewhat experience....I did not downvote your question

Answer (score 1):

$y=\dfrac{1-x^2}{4+x^2}\iff (y+1)x^2+4y-1=0$

This quadratic has obviously real solutions in the domain of definition so

$\Delta=-4(y+1)(4y-1)\ge 0\iff -1\le y\le \frac 14$